# File is being used by another process .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file-io

I need to create/append a text file and write some data in that. When I write the below code to my ASP.NET application, it gives the error that file is being used by another process.

```
if (!File.Exists(path\file))
    File.CreateText(path\file);
using(StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Server.MapPath(path\file)))
{
    sw.WriteLine("Text Data");
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you are using the file within another process try to release it before. And declare intention locks before open the file (as read or write). That could help.

Comment: The `sw.Close()` is, I believe, not needed since you have the StreamWriter in a using block.

Comment: The first thing to do is find out what process is holding the lock (or perhaps which processes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a file like that in the code below and close the file after creating it..

```
if (!File.Exists(""))
{            
    StreamWriter sr =  File.CreateText("");
    sr.Close();
}
```

Take a look at this example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
This will show you to how you can create a text file.

OR, you can create a text file in this way; The code below is from MSDN

```
if (!File.Exists(path)) 
{
    // Create a file to write to.
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
    {

    }   
}
```

Comment: In his posted code, StreamWriter is both in a using block and explicitly closed.

Comment: Can you see his first two lines of code, where he trying to create file, when it does't exist. This code is tested by the way.

Comment: @Tim; Have look at this example from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Ah - got it.  Saw it but didn't pick up on the nuance.  If the file doesn't exist, his code will be using it (due to the File.CreateText) when it enters the using block.  Sorry for the confusion.  You might want to edit your answer to make it a little clearer as to what you were saying.  Good catch.

Answer (score 5):

If another process has an exclusive lock on a file you want, there's pretty much nothing you can do about it, except for forcefully removing all handles to the file, or killing the process, both of which will result in undefined behaviour (by the other program that has the exclusive lock).

You should either

1. wait for the other program to finish using the file
2. write to another file
3. something else that makes sense.

If you're sure that only your code accesses this file, just go back and make sure you close all handles to a file you've previously opened when you're done with it.

If you haven't already done so (we don't see all your code), you need to close off the open file handle from your `File.CreateText()` call, as it returns a `StreamWriter` with an open handle to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the file open in a text editor? Have you opened it in a text editor recently? If so you should make sure your text editor has been fully closed and its process is killed.

If not, then it probably means some other script, or some previous version of the same script which is stuck in an infinite loop has the file opened. If you can afford to killing all your ASP.NET scripts it would probably fix it.